# split array of objects to multiple lists

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my object list

```
[{id: 3, price: 77}, {id: 2, price: 66}]
```

**What is the cleanest way to extract** this list `[77,66]` from the previous list

Comment: `[{'id': 3, 'price': 77}, {'id': 2, 'price': 66}].map((e) => e['price'])` you may also call `toList()` on the result if you really need a `List`

Comment: thanks man it worked , could you post this as an answer to accept it

Comment: feel free to post a self answer ;-)

Comment: you deserve this :) just go for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of json arrays you can use map()

```
import 'dart:convert';
List<int> convertToList(){
    String response=[{id: 3, price: 77}, {id: 2, price: 66}];//Plain String
    var json=json.decode(response);//Convert it to json object
    return List<int>.from(str.map((item) =>item['price'])); 
}
```

The map() will iterate through all the elements of the array and we will extract only the price as you have requested and put it in another list and return it.
You can get reference from https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/background-parsing

Comment: `Iterable.map()`  method returns `Iterable`, not `List`

Comment: See the code i've pasted use `List.from(yourIterableObject)` to convert it to list

Comment: or just `Iterable.toList()`

Comment: yeah but it will give a list of objects .....but in the `List.from()` you can specify the type like `List<int>.from()`